# Show that $ \tan(\arcsin x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $

Tags: trigonometry

Show that $ \tan(\arcsin x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $
I don't know where to start.

Comment: For $0\lt x\lt 1$, draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and one of the sides equal to $x$. Then take care of other values of $x$, namely $x=1$, $0$, and $-1\le x\lt 0$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368603/how-do-i-write-a-trig-function-that-includes-inverses-in-terms-of-another-variab

Comment: @Harish Why [was this tagged](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1457443/revisions) (proof-verification)? If you read the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info), you will see that this tag is supposed to be used if the OP wrote down a proof of some fact and they want to ask whether the proof is correct. But the OP did not post any proof of the equality in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Notice, let $$\sin^{-1}(x)=\theta \implies x=\sin \theta $$
$\forall\ \ 0<\theta<\pi/2 \implies \ \sin\theta>0, \ \ \cos \theta>0$

Now, we know that $$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos\theta}$$
$$=\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}$$
Now, setting  $x=\sin\theta $
$$\tan\theta =\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Now, setting $\theta=\sin^{-1}(x)$ , we get 
$$\tan(\sin^{-1}(x)) =\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Could someone please tell me what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: Please edit the answer. I had meant to upvote it but in a moving vehicle and on my cell, the error happened. Before I could notice and correct it, the 5 min limit was over. Please edit something so I can correct my error

Comment: Once again, sorry, nothing wrong with the answer, we just had to bypass the system in order to correct an error on my part.

Comment: No need to say sorry again, It's OK for me if you give some reason by posting comment. Thanks!

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot why do you set $0<\theta<\pi/2$ while $sin^{-1}x$ is defined between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$?

Comment: @ImreVégh: it is because $0<x<1$

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Why can't x also be $-1<x<0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Setting $\sin^{-1} x = t$, for $|t| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then we get $x = \sin t$ and $\frac{1}{\tan^2 t}+1 = \frac{1}{\sin^2 t}$.