# Identity $\arctan{\frac{1-\beta}{2\sqrt{\beta}}}=\arcsin{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}$

Tags: trigonometry

In the book, Control Systems Engineering - frequency design, the author used the equality $$\phi_{max}=\arctan{\frac{1-\beta}{2\sqrt{\beta}}}=\arcsin{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}$$

Is this some famous identity?
Am I seriously missing out since I've never seen this formula before.

Edit:
Using the formula on the comments:
$$\sin{\arctan{\theta}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
Let $\theta= \frac{1-\beta}{2\sqrt{\beta}}$

$$\arctan{\theta}=\arcsin{\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}}}
$$

$$\arctan{\theta}=\arcsin{\frac{1-\beta^2}{\beta^2+2\beta+1}}
$$
Thus

$$\arctan{\frac{1-\beta}{2\sqrt{\beta}}}=\arcsin{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really new.

Let $\tan\theta=(1-\beta)/2\sqrt{\beta}$ with $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$. Then using $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$ with $\sec\theta>0$ we have

$\sec\theta=\sqrt{(1-\beta)^2+4\beta}/(2\sqrt{\beta})=\sqrt{1+2\beta+\beta^2}/(2\sqrt{\beta}=(1+\beta)/2\sqrt{\beta}$

The sign on the square toot is controlled by the requirement $\beta>0$ for the initial arctangent to be real. So then

$\sin\theta=(\tan\theta)(\cos\theta)=\dfrac{(1-\beta)/2\sqrt{\beta}}{(1+\beta)/2\sqrt{\beta}}$

$=(1-\beta)/(1+\beta)$

as claimed.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Let use [trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_between_trigonometric_functions_and_inverse_trigonometric_functions):

$$\tan(\arcsin x)=\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

which can be easily estabilshed by the following scheme:

[image]
(credit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Trigonometric_functions_and_inverse3.svg))

Refer also to the related:

- [Show that $ \tan(\arcsin x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457443/505767)

Comment: +1 for the beautiful illustration. Can you provide me the font used in the picture if possible?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I've indicated the source, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Trigonometric_functions_and_inverse3.svg). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another way to show two functions are equal.

Let:

$$f(x)=\arctan{\frac{1-x}{2\sqrt{x}}}$$
$$g(x)=\arcsin{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$

Both are defined and $C^1$ for $x>0$.

Now,

$$\arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$\arcsin'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Therefore

$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{1-x}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)'\frac{1}{1+\left(\dfrac{1-x}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)^2}=\frac{-2\sqrt{x}-(1-x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{4x}\cdot\frac{4x}{4x+1-2x+x^2}\\
=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\cdot\frac{-x-1}{(1+x)^2}=-\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt x}$$

$$g'(x)=\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)'\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2}}=\frac{-(1+x)-(1-x)}{(1+x)^2}\cdot\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{(1+x)^2-(1-x)^2}}\\
=-\frac{2}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x}}=-\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt x}$$

Hence $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for $x>0$. Since $f(1)=g(1)=0$, we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: (+1) However, please let me ask: Since the two functions are equal only for $x>0$, I think that generality is lost

Comment: @Yami They are not defined for $x<0$, and $f$ is not defined at $0$ either, while $g$ is defined but not differentiable. What generality exactly is lost?